# Undo is working for only first replaced text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here I am using Ctrl+Z for undoing the replaced text, I have a scenario that, in text-area, I have a sentence with multiple words, where I select first word and replaced with stars,later I select another word and replaced with stars. But when did Ctrl+Z it is only working for latest selected word and not working for previous words.

JavaScript:

```
   var selection = {};

function undo(e) {
    var evtobj = window.event? window.event : e;
    if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey && selection.text) {
        evtobj.preventDefault();
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
        var allText = txtarea.value;
        var newText = allText.substring(0, selection.start) + selection.text + allText.substring(selection.finish, allText.length);
        txtarea.value = newText;
    }
}

function getSel() {
    // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    // obtain the index of the first selected character
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    // obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    //obtain all Text
    var allText = txtarea.value;

    selection.text = allText.substring(start, finish);
    selection.start = start;
    selection.finish = finish;

    // obtain the selected text
    var sel = allText.substring(start, finish);
    sel = sel.replace(/[\S]/g, "*"); //append te text;
    var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + sel + allText.substring(finish, allText.length);
    txtarea.value = newText;

    $('#newpost').offset({top: 0, left: 0}).hide();
}
function closePopUp() {
    $('#newpost').offset({top: 0, left: 0}).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    closePopUp();
    var newpost = $('#newpost');
    $('#mytextarea').on('select', function (e) {
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
        var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
        var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
        newpost.offset(getCursorXY(txtarea, start, 20)).show();
        newpost.find('div').text('replace with stars');
    }).on('input', () => selection.text = null);
    document.onkeydown = undo;

});

var getCursorXY = function getCursorXY(input, selectionPoint, offset) {
    var inputX = input.offsetLeft,
        inputY = input.offsetTop;
    // create a dummy element that will be a clone of our input

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    // get the computed style of the input and clone it onto the dummy element
    var copyStyle = getComputedStyle(input);
    var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
    var _didIteratorError = false;
    var _iteratorError = undefined;

    try {
        for (var _iterator = copyStyle[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done) ; _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
            var prop = _step.value;

            div.style[prop] = copyStyle[prop];
        }
        // we need a character that will replace whitespace when filling our dummy element 
        // if it's a single line <input/>
    } catch (err) {
        _didIteratorError = true;
        _iteratorError = err;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
                _iterator.return();
            }
        } finally {
            if (_didIteratorError) {
                throw _iteratorError;
            }
        }
    }

    var swap = '.';
    var inputValue = input.tagName === 'INPUT' ? input.value.replace(/ /g, swap) : input.value;
    // set the div content to that of the textarea up until selection
    var textContent = inputValue.substr(0, selectionPoint);
    // set the text content of the dummy element div
    div.textContent = textContent;
    if (input.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') div.style.height = 'auto';
    // if a single line input then the div needs to be single line and not break out like a text area
    if (input.tagName === 'INPUT') div.style.width = 'auto';
    // create a marker element to obtain caret position
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    // give the span the textContent of remaining content so that the recreated dummy element 
    // is as close as possible
    span.textContent = inputValue.substr(selectionPoint) || '.';
    // append the span marker to the div
    div.appendChild(span);
    // append the dummy element to the body
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    // get the marker position, this is the caret position top and left relative to the input
    var spanX = span.offsetLeft,
        spanY = span.offsetTop;
    // lastly, remove that dummy element
    // NOTE:: can comment this out for debugging purposes if you want to see where that span is rendered

    document.body.removeChild(div);
    // return an object with the x and y of the caret. account for input positioning 
    // so that you don't need to wrap the input
    return {
        left: inputX + spanX,
        top: inputY + spanY + offset
    };
};
```

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vjJNKyZ8sUjhtbd1DGqH?p=preview).

Comment: That seems to be because you have multiple selections yet only keeping track of one selection, and the whole `undo` logic relies on the `selection` obj. So you need to rethink a little bit, to use arrays + objects

Comment: @Adelin Thanks..Can you plz elaborate it..I am I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually control all your `textarea` changes.

Here I created the `edits` array which is populated with `textarea` text on change every few seconds (you can control it using the `saveInterval` variable).
You also can set the max length of this array using `maxHistorySize`. When the array is full, the old changes are lost.

```js
var edits = [""];
var interval = true;
var maxHistorySize = 10;
var saveInterval = 3000;

function undo(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? window.event : e;
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
          evtobj.preventDefault();
          var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
          var previousText = edits.length === 1 ? edits[0] : edits.pop();
          if (previousText !== undefined) {
              txtarea.value = previousText;
          }
      }
}

function getSel() {
    // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    // obtain the index of the first selected character
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    // obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    //obtain all Text
    var allText = txtarea.value;
    
    edits.push(allText);
    if (edits.length > maxHistorySize) edits.shift();

    // obtain the selected text
    var sel = Array(finish - start + 1).join("*");
    //append te text;
    var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + sel + allText.substring(finish, allText.length);
    txtarea.value = newText;
    
    $('#newpost').offset({top: 0, left: 0}).hide();
}
function closePopUp() {
    $('#newpost').offset({top: 0, left: 0}).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    closePopUp();
    var newpost = $('#newpost');
    $('#mytextarea').on('select', function (e) {
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
        var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
        var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
        newpost.offset(getCursorXY(txtarea, start, 20)).show();
        newpost.find('div').text(Array(finish - start + 1).join("*"));
    }).on('input', function() {
        if (interval) {
            interval = false;
            edits.push($(this).val());
            if (edits.length > maxHistorySize) edits.shift();
            setTimeout(() => interval = true, saveInterval);
        }
    });
    document.onkeydown = undo;
});

const getCursorXY = (input, selectionPoint, offset) => {
  const {
    offsetLeft: inputX,
    offsetTop: inputY,
  } = input
  // create a dummy element that will be a clone of our input
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  // get the computed style of the input and clone it onto the dummy element
  const copyStyle = getComputedStyle(input)
  for (const prop of copyStyle) {
    div.style[prop] = copyStyle[prop]
  }
  // we need a character that will replace whitespace when filling our dummy element 
  // if it's a single line <input/>
  const swap = '.'
  const inputValue = input.tagName === 'INPUT' ? input.value.replace(/ /g, swap) : input.value
  // set the div content to that of the textarea up until selection
  const textContent = inputValue.substr(0, selectionPoint)
  // set the text content of the dummy element div
  div.textContent = textContent
  if (input.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') div.style.height = 'auto'
  // if a single line input then the div needs to be single line and not break out like a text area
  if (input.tagName === 'INPUT') div.style.width = 'auto'
  // create a marker element to obtain caret position
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  // give the span the textContent of remaining content so that the recreated dummy element 
  // is as close as possible
  span.textContent = inputValue.substr(selectionPoint) || '.'
  // append the span marker to the div
  div.appendChild(span)
  // append the dummy element to the body
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  // get the marker position, this is the caret position top and left relative to the input
  const { offsetLeft: spanX, offsetTop: spanY } = span
  // lastly, remove that dummy element
  // NOTE:: can comment this out for debugging purposes if you want to see where that span is rendered
  document.body.removeChild(div)
  // return an object with the x and y of the caret. account for input positioning 
  // so that you don't need to wrap the input
  return {
    left: inputX + spanX,
    top: inputY + spanY + offset,
  }
}
```

```css
#mytextarea {width: 600px; height: 200px; overflow:hidden; position:fixed}
#newpost {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ffffdc;
    border:1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding-right:5px; 
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
}
#newpost span {
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
#newpost div {
    color:#0000ff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width: auto;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
 <body>
    <textArea id="mytextarea"></textArea>
    <div id="newpost">
        <span onclick="closePopUp();">&#735;</span>
        <div onclick="getSel()"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you  plz check this link..Iam getting this type of issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501953/div-position-is-outside-of-text-area-for-multi-selection-of-text-in-text-area

Comment: @anub note that there is no such issue in the attached snippet ;)

Comment: the popup is out of the text-area,when large text is selected

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic from using a single `selection` object to using an array of `selection` objects, like this:

1. Initialize to `selections` instead of `selection`

   ```
   var selections = [];
   ```
2. When `getSel()` is called, make sure you update to `push` to array:

   ```
   function getSel() {
       // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
       var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
       // obtain the index of the first selected character
       var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
       // obtain the index of the last selected character
       var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
       //obtain all Text
       var allText = txtarea.value;

       selections.push({
         start: start,
         finish: finish,
         text: allText.substring(start, finish)
       });
       // obtain the selected text
       var sel = allText.substring(start, finish);
       sel = sel.replace(/[\S]/g, "*"); //append te text;
       var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + sel + allText.substring(finish, allText.length);
       txtarea.value = newText;

       $('#newpost').offset({top: 0, left: 0}).hide();
   }
   ```
3. As such, we need to update `undo` function, as follows:

   ```
   function undo(e) {
       var evtobj = window.event? window.event : e;

       if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
           evtobj.preventDefault();

           if (selections.length === 0) alert ("Can't do more undos");
           else {
               var thisSelection = selections.pop();
               var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
               var allText = txtarea.value;
               var newText = allText.substring(0, thisSelection.start) + thisSelection.text + allText.substring(thisSelection.finish, allText.length);
               txtarea.value = newText;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Lastly, remove the `on('input')` event listener from `$('#mytextarea')` as I don't think it's needed

Here's [the plunk with all the changes](https://plnkr.co/edit/xFUOG3zEysQFQrXDieWA?p=preview)

Comment: plz check this link once..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501953/div-position-is-outside-of-text-area-for-multi-selection-of-text-in-text-area

Comment: why for no selection of text,ctrl+z is not working(i.e; last edited text is not working)

Comment: You mean if you don't edit with *** but with something else?

Comment: @anub then you need a whole new implementation. Current logic you implement is applicable only when replacing with stars.

Comment: @anub no problem. Oh and since you removed the accepted checkmark, you can also remove the upvote - clearly my answer was not what you were looking for - as it doesn't implement what you need. And since maybe is not even useful to you, you might as well downvote

Comment: nothing like that,you helped me..n you tried my question..thanks for dat.