# div position is outside of text area for multi-selection of text in text-area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing issue with multi-selection of text in text-area,the div is placed out of the text-area but for single selection word it is working fine..

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
closePopUp();
var newpost = $('#newpost');
$('#mytextarea').on('select', function (e) {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    newpost.offset(getCursorXY(txtarea, start, 20)).show();
    newpost.find('div').text('replace with stars');
});
document.onkeydown = undo;

});
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vjJNKyZ8sUjhtbd1DGqH?p=preview)

The is issue is shown in below image:

[image]

Comment: **(1)** The plunker has a jquery issue and won't load correctly **(2)** I don't understand what the problem is, exactly. Can you please explain what you mean with *the div is placed out of the text-area*?

Comment: @Adelin check once plunker..it is working now.Here when I select multiple lines the div(replace stars is showing out of the text area).

Comment: `newpost.offset(getCursorXY(txtarea, finish, 20)).show();`

Comment: @Adelin it is not working.